# Error when mexifying C code using matlab which is linked with an object assembled with nasm

Tags: c, matlab, assembly, nasm, mex

I am trying to mexify C code in Matlab which is linked with an object that I assembled using nasm. When I try to mexify the code I receive an error from Matlab. Here is the command I use to mexify the code:

```
    mex main.c hello.o
```

Here is the C code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include "mex.h"

    extern char * helloWorld();

    void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])  {
        char * sentence = helloWorld();
        printf("%s\n", sentence);
    }
```

Here is the assembly code:

```
    global helloWorld

    section .data
        greeting: db "Hello, World", 0
    section .text
    helloWorld:
        mov eax, greeting
        ret
```

The command I use to assemble the code is:

```
    nasm -felf64 -gdwarf2 -o hello.o hello.asm
```

This is the error I receive when I try to mexify the C code:

```
    /usr/bin/ld: hello.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.data' can not be used
    when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    hello.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There is no -fPIC flag for nasm. I tried using the get_GOT macro as well as default rel, but I still get the same error. All help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: It's not the assembler that generates position-independent code, but the programmer itself.

Comment: I just wanted to point that out since I didn't want anybody to tell me to use the -fPIC flag.

Comment: `-gdwarf2` isn't going to do anything. `-Fdwarf` is as close as Nasm will come. `default rel` might help. Using `rax` instead of `eax` might help. Good luck!

Comment: can you try it first with a regular C program instead of a MEX-file (replace `mexFunction` with `main`)? You can find out the `gcc` arguments that `mex` is using: `cc = mex.getCompilerConfigurations` to compare

Comment: It works fine when compiling with gcc and using main as the starting point.

Comment: @OshaMan: try using FrankKotler's suggestions, it worked for me on Win64 (as shown in my post below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am on a Windows machine (WinXP 32-bit) with VS2010 as compiler. Here's what I did:

- download NASM assembler for [Windows](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.10.09/win32/nasm-2.10.09-win32.zip)
- add underscore to the name of exported symbol in the assembly code:

  ```
  global _helloWorld

  section .data
      greeting: db "Hello, World", 0
  section .text
  _helloWorld:
      mov eax, greeting
      ret
  ```
- compile the assembly code as following: `nasm -f win32 -o hello.obj hello.asm`
- in MATLAB, compile the MEX-file linking against the generated object file:

  ```
  >> mex main_mex.c hello.obj
  ```

  As I said, `mex` is previously configured to use Visual Studio 2010 for compilation.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include "mex.h"

  extern char* helloWorld();

  void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
  {
      char *sentence = helloWorld();
      mexPrintf("%s\n", sentence);
  }
  ```
- run the MEX-function:

  ```
  >> main_mex
  Hello, World
  ```

---

### EDIT:

On 64-bit Windows, I made the following changes:

```
bits 64        ; specify 64-bit target processor mode
default rel    ; RIP-relative adresses

section .text
global helloWorld      ; export function symbol (not mangled with an initial _)
helloWorld:
    mov rax, greeting  ; return string
    ret

section .data
    greeting: db "Hello, World", 0
```

then:

```
>> !nasm -f win64 -o hello.obj hello.asm
>> mex -largeArrayDims hello_mex.c hello.obj
>> hello_mex
Hello, World
```

Comment: My assembly is not very good, but when I tried this on a 64-bit Windows (didnt have to add underscores), it failed during linking: `error LNK2017: 'ADDR32' relocation to '.data' invalid without /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO. fatal error LNK1165: link failed because of fixup error`. I think the issue here has to do with 32-64 bitness, but I dont know how to fix this..

Comment: I tried: `mex -largeArrayDims LINKFLAGS="$LINKFLAGS /LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO" main_mex.c hello.obj` but that was ignored with the same error message `LINK : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/LARGEADDRESSAWARE:NO' due to '/DLL' specification`

Comment: ok I managed to fix the above linking problem on Win64 by using `rax` register instead of `eax`, that way NASM generates ADDR64 relocations instead of ADDR32 (confirmed by running: `dumpbin /all hello.obj`): http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/nasm-effaddr.html, http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.3, http://www.briancbecker.com/blog/2010/porting-32-bit-nasm-code-to-64-bit/

Comment: Thank You. I will try this solution when I get to a computer that has Matlab installed on it. What does !nasm do when you assemble the assembly code. Also will this solution work on linux?

Comment: @OshaMan: dont know if it will work on Linux, you'll have to try it.. `!` in MATLAB is used to issue system commands, same as `system('nasm ...')`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/creating-opening-changing-and-deleting-files-and-folders.html#f0-38522. You can always run your commands from the shell if you want

Comment: Is assembling the code from Matlab part of the solution or can I assemble it from the terminal?

Comment: @OshaMan: no, MATLAB does not contain an assembler, I am just invoking an external program from inside MATLAB (in this case the NASM assembler), without having to switch to the system shell. Use the terminal as usual if you want :)